# In c++ priority queue, do I need to re push an object again after modifying its properties?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm providing the whole code which is a solution of fractional knapsack problem. At the end of the code I'll explain the problem,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>

#define MAX_WEIGHT 5

using namespace std;

class Item{
public:
    int weight;
    int benefit;
    float weightPerBenefit;
    int selectedWeight = 0;

    Item(int weight, int benefit){
        this->weight = weight;
        this->benefit = benefit;
        this->weightPerBenefit = (float)this->weight/(float)this->benefit;
    }

    void setSelectedWeight(int w){
        this->selectedWeight = w;
    }

    bool operator < (const Item &item) const{
        return weightPerBenefit < item.weightPerBenefit;
    }
};

void displayItems(priority_queue<Item> items){
    while(!items.empty()){
        Item item = items.top();
        items.pop();
        cout << "Item Benefit: " << item.benefit << ", Selected Weight: " << item.selectedWeight << endl;;
    }
}

void fractionalKnapsack(priority_queue<Item> items){
    int rw = MAX_WEIGHT;
    while(!items.empty()){
        Item item = items.top();
        items.pop();
        int w = item.weight;
        if(w > rw){
            item.setSelectedWeight(rw);
            break;
        }
        else{
            //cout << w << endl;
            item.setSelectedWeight(w);
            rw = rw-w;
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int size;
    cout << "Enter total number of items: ";
    cin >> size;
    priority_queue<Item> items;

    int data[size][2];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout << "Enter item weight: ";
        cin >> data[i][0];
        cout << "Enter item benefit: ";
        cin >> data[i][1];
        cout << endl;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        Item item(data[i][0], data[i][1]);
        items.push(item);
    }

    //displayItems(items);
    fractionalKnapsack(items);
    displayItems(items);

}
```

So, the problem is whenever the fractionalKnapsack function is called and the object's property is updated, after the display method it shows the property value 0 which was defined at the start. It doesn't update to the new value.

I don't know a lot about priority_queue, it has to be done using priority queue. I'm out of ideas why this bug is happening.

Comment: `fractionalKnapsack` empties a copy of the queue, leaving the original untouched. And there is no way to modify the elements inside a `priority_queue`, anyway.

Comment: Also, the greedy algorithm is "take as much as you can of the 'best' item, then the second best, and so on". This doesn't require any modifications to the elements – just pop them until your knapsack is full or you run out of stuff.

Comment: I think you took a wrong turn when you decided to store the result in the same place as the input.

Answer (score 0):

ref : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/top/

`std::priority_queue::top` Returns a constant reference to the top element in the priority_queue.

```cpp
Item item = items.top();
items.pop();
item.setSelectedWeight(rw);
```

There, you just create a local variable, and use it. Should reinsert it back, I think.

PS: for some STL get method. If it's safe to change it value, it will return a reference, otherwise const reference.